# Re-using peers/nodes in Hyperledger Fabric for 2 different DLT networks

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I was exploring the channels feature of Hyperledger Fabric. I understand that separate channels is only for same Blockchain (DLT) network. I am just exploring the possibility in Docker Containers, for building 2 PoCs.

If a node/peer is configured for an organisation in one DLT (multi-org) network, can it be re-used for a different organisation in another DLT (multi-org) network?

Eg. Lets say a peer is configured for a Supplier in one network (1st Use case), can it be re-used as a peer for Logistics Company in another network (2nd use case)?

Please note that both networks should be up and running at the same-time.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it practically but theoretically, it is possible. Why?
The criteria of a peer joining a channel to another network is dependent upon whether its root CA certificates are in that channel's configuration block or not, along with its MSP-ID.

And network itself is nothing but the information about the organization, that decided whether a peer can join a channel or not. If that information is in the configuration block, and it matches the peer, it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, The network you keep referring to is actually a consortium of some organizations.

First things first, A peer is always associated with a particular organization and the crypto files and organization certificates are bootstrapped to the docker container of that peer.

However, The policies governing the network can be varied across the consortiums and/or channels in each consortium. The organization may have read/write access in one consortium and in others it may have separate permissions.

The peer cannot be decoupled from an organization but the organization itself can be decoupled from the consortium.

Comment: Thanks Neo. We don't do it production. We are working on 2 Proof of Concepts - PoCs, where we need to prove that Blockchain solves the actual problems. We have only 3 VMs. We need to use these 3 VMs for both the PoCs. One Network/Consortium has 3 organisations of OEM, Supplier 1, Supplier 2 and Other Consortium has OEM, Supplier 1, Logistics 1. I can understand that first 2 VMs can be re-used, because they belong to the same orgs in both networks. The 3rd one is what the problem is, we have to re-use it, in such a way that we run both PoCs in same 3 VMs.

Comment: We can do it, if we name & configure the 3rd VM is generic manner, so that we could identify (conceptually and manually) in the Network as Supplier and in other network as Logistics.

Comment: I am just checking, if it can be done with the help of containerisation, instead of handling it in the above mentioned way

Comment: You can have both the network you mentioned on a single VM, you can run multiple Docker containers in just one VM by defining them in yaml file. You just need 4 orgs as you said i.e atleast 4 peer containers in that VM, create 2 consortium and add the required orgs to the consortium.

Comment: For the Purpose of PoC this will be well sufficient, only in production you would want each VM to be seperate instance.